# Mono Object is not showing in postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I have the following controller in a springboot application which I use to GET an employee based on given employeeID.

```
@GetMapping(path = "employee/{empId}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> getEmployee(@PathVariable(name = "empId") String empID,
        @RequestParam(name = "showExtraDetails", defaultValue = "false") boolean showExtraDetails) {

    Mono<Employee> employeeFound = employeeService.getEmployee(empID, showExtraDetails);

    if (employeeFound != null) {
        return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(employeeFound, HttpStatus.OK));
    } 
}
```

I can see the status code 200 in postman but I cannot see the details of the employee as the response body. Instead I see the following:

```
{
"scanAvailable": true
}
```

Is there a way to display the employee attributes without blocking the stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, but it might have to do with putting the `Mono<Employee>` in the `ResponseEntity` directly. This should work:

```
return employeeService.getEmployee(empID, showExtraDetails)
  .map(employee-> new ResponseEntity<>(employee, HttpStatus.OK))
  .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
```

Comment: Yes, That worked. Thank you. What difference does it make when you use the Mono<Employee> within the ResponseEntity ?

Comment: I am making assumptions, but I think the desired return value is `Mono<ResponseEntity<Employee>>` but actually was `Mono<ResponseEntity<Mono<Employee>>>`. Meaning that `Mono<>` the response body.